# Prove that an n-vertex tree has exactly $3\cdot2^{n-1}$ proper $3$-colorings.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Could a possible solution be to show how many triangles an n-vertex tree could have? Each vertex in the triangle will have a different color, but then I will need a way to subtract off the shared vertices.

Comment: Start at one vertex, then at each stage colour a new vertex adjacent to just one you've already coloured.

Answer (score 1):

There are no triangles (or cycles of any length) in a tree.

Instead, try induction on the number of vertices by reducing the $n$-vertex tree to an $(n-1)$-vertex tree by removing a leaf.

Comment: How does the 3*2^(n-1) come about?